# Android RecyclerView Partial Swipe with Delete Button

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, onclicklistener, swipe

I am trying to implement a partial swipe in `RecyclerView` and add a delete button. I would like to delete the swiped row only after the user clicks the delete button. I am using `ItemTouchHelper`. `SimpleCallback` and was able to achieve the partial swipe with the code below. I have two pending tasks:

1. I am implementing partial swipe using the `onChildDraw` method. I am currently drawing a red rectangle on partial swipe. I would want to add the text "Delete" inside it. Is it possible to add a Button instead of drawing a rectangle?
2. How do I add the click listener on the rectange/button to perform the delete action.

   ```
   @Override
   public void onChildDraw(Canvas c, RecyclerView recyclerView, RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder, float dX, float dY, int actionState, boolean isCurrentlyActive) {
       try {

           Bitmap icon;
           if (actionState == ItemTouchHelper.ACTION_STATE_SWIPE) {
               View itemView = viewHolder.itemView;

               float height = (float) itemView.getBottom() - (float) itemView.getTop();
               float width = height / 5;
               viewHolder.itemView.setTranslationX(dX / 5);


               Paint paint = new Paint();

               paint.setColor(Color.parseColor("#D32F2F"));
               RectF background = new RectF((float) itemView.getRight() + dX / 5, (float) itemView.getTop(), (float) itemView.getRight(), (float) itemView.getBottom());

              RectF icon_dest = new RectF((float) (itemView.getRight() + dX /7), (float) itemView.getTop()+width, (float) itemView.getRight()+dX/20, (float) itemView.getBottom()-width);

              c.drawBitmap(null, null, icon_dest, paint);
           } else {
               super.onChildDraw(c, recyclerView, viewHolder, dX, dY, actionState, isCurrentlyActive);
           }
       } catch (Exception e) {
           e.printStackTrace();
       }
   }
   ```

Comment: check this out https://www.learn2crack.com/2016/02/custom-swipe-recyclerview.html

Answer (score 1):

To answer your questions:

1. Yes. It's possible, but not in onChildDraw method. There are a lot
   3rd party libraries use a two-layer approach. The first layer is
   your item view, the second has all the buttons. When you swipe, it
   reveals the button layer, and you can handle click event by setting
   buttons' OnClickListener.
2. To add OnClickListener to the buttons you drawn in onChildDraw
   method, you will have to set recylerView.setOnTouchListener to get
   (x,y) on screen. Please check AdamWei's post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38811533/creating-buttons-and-button-click-under-recyclerview-item-when-it-swiped-swip-t) for
   instruction.

You can also check my post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44965278/recyclerview-itemtouchhelper-buttons-on-swipe/45062745?noredirect=1#comment77123056_45062745). I have implemented the desired effect by using ItemTouchHelper.SimpleCallback. It's a simple helper class, easy to use.

Comment: Please avoid links as they might be broken in the future. This would be acceptable on Quora but not on SO. Please explain how to solve this issue in your answer.