# RecyclerView ItemTouchHelper Buttons on Swipe

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, itemtouchhelper

I am trying to port some iOS functionality to Android.

I intent to create a table where on swipe to the left shows 2 button: Edit and Delete.

[image]

I have been playing with it and I know I am very close. The secret really lies on the method OnChildDraw.

I would like to Draw a Rect that fits the text Delete then draw the Edit text besides it with their respective background color. The remaining white space when clicked should restore the row to its initial position.

I have managed to paint the background while the user is swiping to the sides but I don't know how to add the listeners and once it is swiped to the side, the dragging function begins to misbehave.

I am working on Xamarin but pure java solutions also are accepted as I can easily port them to c#.

```
    public class SavedPlacesItemTouchHelper : ItemTouchHelper.SimpleCallback
    {
        private SavedPlacesRecyclerviewAdapter adapter;
        private Paint paint = new Paint();
        private Context context;

        public SavedPlacesItemTouchHelper(Context context, SavedPlacesRecyclerviewAdapter adapter) : base(ItemTouchHelper.ActionStateIdle, ItemTouchHelper.Left)
        {
            this.context = context;
            this.adapter = adapter;
        }

        public override bool OnMove(RecyclerView recyclerView, RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder, RecyclerView.ViewHolder target)
        {
            return false;
        }

        public override void OnSwiped(RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder, int direction)
        {
        }

        public override void OnChildDraw(Canvas c, RecyclerView recyclerView, RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder, float dX, float dY, int actionState, bool isCurrentlyActive)
        {
            float translationX = dX;
            View itemView = viewHolder.ItemView;
            float height = (float)itemView.Bottom - (float)itemView.Top;

            if (actionState == ItemTouchHelper.ActionStateSwipe && dX <= 0) // Swiping Left
            {
                 translationX = -Math.Min(-dX, height * 2);
                paint.Color = Color.Red;
                RectF background = new RectF((float)itemView.Right + translationX, (float)itemView.Top, (float)itemView.Right, (float)itemView.Bottom);
                c.DrawRect(background, paint);

                //viewHolder.ItemView.TranslationX = translationX;
            }
            else if (actionState == ItemTouchHelper.ActionStateSwipe && dX > 0) // Swiping Right
            {
                translationX = Math.Min(dX, height * 2);
                paint.Color = Color.Red;
                RectF background = new RectF((float)itemView.Right + translationX, (float)itemView.Top, (float)itemView.Right, (float)itemView.Bottom);
                c.DrawRect(background, paint);
            }

            base.OnChildDraw(c, recyclerView, viewHolder, translationX, dY, actionState, isCurrentlyActive);
        }
    }
}
```

This is what I currently have.

If you know how to add listeners or any suggestions please leave a comment!

UPDATE:

I just realized that on double tap on the white remaining space of the row already restore the row to its initial state. Not a single tap though :(

Answer (score 137, accepted):

I struggled with the same issue, and tried to find a solution online. Most of the solutions use a two-layer approach (one layer view item, another layer buttons), but I want to stick with ItemTouchHelper only. At the end, I came up with a worked solution. Please check below.

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.Paint;
import android.graphics.Point;
import android.graphics.Rect;
import android.graphics.RectF;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.support.v7.widget.helper.ItemTouchHelper;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.GestureDetector;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.View;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.LinkedList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Queue;

public abstract class SwipeHelper extends ItemTouchHelper.SimpleCallback {

    public static final int BUTTON_WIDTH = YOUR_WIDTH_IN_PIXEL_PER_BUTTON
    private RecyclerView recyclerView;
    private List<UnderlayButton> buttons;
    private GestureDetector gestureDetector;
    private int swipedPos = -1;
    private float swipeThreshold = 0.5f;
    private Map<Integer, List<UnderlayButton>> buttonsBuffer;
    private Queue<Integer> recoverQueue;

    private GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener gestureListener = new GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener(){
        @Override
        public boolean onSingleTapConfirmed(MotionEvent e) {
            for (UnderlayButton button : buttons){
                if(button.onClick(e.getX(), e.getY()))
                    break;
            }

            return true;
        }
    };

    private View.OnTouchListener onTouchListener = new View.OnTouchListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent e) {
            if (swipedPos < 0) return false;
            Point point = new Point((int) e.getRawX(), (int) e.getRawY());

            RecyclerView.ViewHolder swipedViewHolder = recyclerView.findViewHolderForAdapterPosition(swipedPos);
            View swipedItem = swipedViewHolder.itemView;
            Rect rect = new Rect();
            swipedItem.getGlobalVisibleRect(rect);

            if (e.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN || e.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP ||e.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE) {
                if (rect.top < point.y && rect.bottom > point.y)
                    gestureDetector.onTouchEvent(e);
                else {
                    recoverQueue.add(swipedPos);
                    swipedPos = -1;
                    recoverSwipedItem();
                }
            }
            return false;
        }
    };

    public SwipeHelper(Context context, RecyclerView recyclerView) {
        super(0, ItemTouchHelper.LEFT);
        this.recyclerView = recyclerView;
        this.buttons = new ArrayList<>();
        this.gestureDetector = new GestureDetector(context, gestureListener);
        this.recyclerView.setOnTouchListener(onTouchListener);
        buttonsBuffer = new HashMap<>();
        recoverQueue = new LinkedList<Integer>(){
            @Override
            public boolean add(Integer o) {
                if (contains(o))
                    return false;
                else
                    return super.add(o);
            }
        };

        attachSwipe();
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onMove(RecyclerView recyclerView, RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder, RecyclerView.ViewHolder target) {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public void onSwiped(RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder, int direction) {
        int pos = viewHolder.getAdapterPosition();

        if (swipedPos != pos)
            recoverQueue.add(swipedPos);

        swipedPos = pos;

        if (buttonsBuffer.containsKey(swipedPos))
            buttons = buttonsBuffer.get(swipedPos);
        else
            buttons.clear();

        buttonsBuffer.clear();
        swipeThreshold = 0.5f * buttons.size() * BUTTON_WIDTH;
        recoverSwipedItem();
    }

    @Override
    public float getSwipeThreshold(RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder) {
        return swipeThreshold;
    }

    @Override
    public float getSwipeEscapeVelocity(float defaultValue) {
        return 0.1f * defaultValue;
    }

    @Override
    public float getSwipeVelocityThreshold(float defaultValue) {
        return 5.0f * defaultValue;
    }

    @Override
    public void onChildDraw(Canvas c, RecyclerView recyclerView, RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder, float dX, float dY, int actionState, boolean isCurrentlyActive) {
        int pos = viewHolder.getAdapterPosition();
        float translationX = dX;
        View itemView = viewHolder.itemView;

        if (pos < 0){
            swipedPos = pos;
            return;
        }

        if(actionState == ItemTouchHelper.ACTION_STATE_SWIPE){
            if(dX < 0) {
                List<UnderlayButton> buffer = new ArrayList<>();

                if (!buttonsBuffer.containsKey(pos)){
                    instantiateUnderlayButton(viewHolder, buffer);
                    buttonsBuffer.put(pos, buffer);
                }
                else {
                    buffer = buttonsBuffer.get(pos);
                }

                translationX = dX * buffer.size() * BUTTON_WIDTH / itemView.getWidth();
                drawButtons(c, itemView, buffer, pos, translationX);
            }
        }

        super.onChildDraw(c, recyclerView, viewHolder, translationX, dY, actionState, isCurrentlyActive);
    }

    private synchronized void recoverSwipedItem(){
        while (!recoverQueue.isEmpty()){
            int pos = recoverQueue.poll();
            if (pos > -1) {
                recyclerView.getAdapter().notifyItemChanged(pos);
            }
        }
    }

    private void drawButtons(Canvas c, View itemView, List<UnderlayButton> buffer, int pos, float dX){
        float right = itemView.getRight();
        float dButtonWidth = (-1) * dX / buffer.size();

        for (UnderlayButton button : buffer) {
            float left = right - dButtonWidth;
            button.onDraw(
                    c,
                    new RectF(
                            left,
                            itemView.getTop(),
                            right,
                            itemView.getBottom()
                    ),
                    pos
            );

            right = left;
        }
    }

    public void attachSwipe(){
        ItemTouchHelper itemTouchHelper = new ItemTouchHelper(this);
        itemTouchHelper.attachToRecyclerView(recyclerView);
    }

    public abstract void instantiateUnderlayButton(RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder, List<UnderlayButton> underlayButtons);

    public static class UnderlayButton {
        private String text;
        private int imageResId;
        private int color;
        private int pos;
        private RectF clickRegion;
        private UnderlayButtonClickListener clickListener;

        public UnderlayButton(String text, int imageResId, int color, UnderlayButtonClickListener clickListener) {
            this.text = text;
            this.imageResId = imageResId;
            this.color = color;
            this.clickListener = clickListener;
        }

        public boolean onClick(float x, float y){
            if (clickRegion != null && clickRegion.contains(x, y)){
                clickListener.onClick(pos);
                return true;
            }

            return false;
        }

        public void onDraw(Canvas c, RectF rect, int pos){
            Paint p = new Paint();

            // Draw background
            p.setColor(color);
            c.drawRect(rect, p);

            // Draw Text
            p.setColor(Color.WHITE);
            p.setTextSize(LayoutHelper.getPx(MyApplication.getAppContext(), 12));

            Rect r = new Rect();
            float cHeight = rect.height();
            float cWidth = rect.width();
            p.setTextAlign(Paint.Align.LEFT);
            p.getTextBounds(text, 0, text.length(), r);
            float x = cWidth / 2f - r.width() / 2f - r.left;
            float y = cHeight / 2f + r.height() / 2f - r.bottom;
            c.drawText(text, rect.left + x, rect.top + y, p);

            clickRegion = rect;
            this.pos = pos;
        }
    }

    public interface UnderlayButtonClickListener {
        void onClick(int pos);
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
SwipeHelper swipeHelper = new SwipeHelper(this, recyclerView) {
    @Override
    public void instantiateUnderlayButton(RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder, List<UnderlayButton> underlayButtons) {
        underlayButtons.add(new SwipeHelper.UnderlayButton(
                "Delete",
                0,
                Color.parseColor("#FF3C30"),
                new SwipeHelper.UnderlayButtonClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(int pos) {
                        // TODO: onDelete
                    }
                }
        ));

        underlayButtons.add(new SwipeHelper.UnderlayButton(
                "Transfer",
                0,
                Color.parseColor("#FF9502"),
                new SwipeHelper.UnderlayButtonClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(int pos) {
                        // TODO: OnTransfer
                    }
                }
        ));
        underlayButtons.add(new SwipeHelper.UnderlayButton(
                "Unshare",
                0,
                Color.parseColor("#C7C7CB"),
                new SwipeHelper.UnderlayButtonClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(int pos) {
                        // TODO: OnUnshare
                    }
                }
        ));
    }
};
```

**Note**: This helper class is designed for left swipe. You can change swipe direction in **SwipeHelper's** constructor, and making changes based on dX in **onChildDraw** method accordingly.

If you want to show image in the button, just make the use of **imageResId** in **UnderlayButton**, and re-implement the **onDraw** method.

There is a known bug, when you swipe an item diagonally from one item to another, the first touched item will flash a little. This could be addressed by decreasing the value of **getSwipeVelocityThreshold**, but this makes harder for user to swipe the item. You can also adjust the swiping feeling by changing two other values in **getSwipeThreshold** and **getSwipeEscapeVelocity**. Check into the ItemTouchHelper source code, the comments are very helpful.

I believe there is a lot place for optimization. This solution just gives an idea if you want to stick with ItemTouchHelper. Please let me know if you have problem using it. Below is a screenshot.

[image]

**Acknowledgment**: this solution is mostly inspired from AdamWei's answer in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38811533/creating-buttons-and-button-click-under-recyclerview-item-when-it-swiped-swip-t)

Comment: I've manage to make it appear with itemTouchHelper, but couldnt click on it... So I changed the implementation for swiping left or right. Sorry, but my question asks a itemTouchHelper solution :D

Comment: @GustavoBaiocchiCosta Hmm, I think this is using itemTouchHelper. Check attachSwipe() methond. In order to make it clickable, you will have to have the help of OnTouchListener, which is implemented in my solution as well. Probably I got your question wrong. Anyway, glad to hear you solved it

Comment: @WenxiZeng i). i tried above code ,its working fine.but one problem i faced.In position 1 is open state ,at position 3 (row) try to swipe on right side ,it close the position 1.ii) how to implement the different view for different row like above gif image.

Comment: @rafeek great to hear it's working for you. to answer your questions, i) this helper class is designed for swiping one item at a time. if you want to keep the previous items opened when a new item swiped, remove the else statement recoverQueue.add(swipedPos); swipedPos = -1; recoverSwipedItem(); in the onTouchListener.OnTouch() method. but I bet that will cause some weird behavior when the buttons clicked. you probably have to write your own logic to handle this situation.  ii) to have different view for different row, all you have to do is to add a switch/if when you add the underlayButtons.

Comment: @rafeek in instantiateUnderlayButton, make the use of viewHolder.getAdapterPosition() to get the pos. and use the pos to get data from you adapter. then use switch/if statement based on your data to instantiate different buttons.

Comment: @WenxiZeng thanks for reply.I understood answer for second question.But i think u didnt get my first question.when first row in open state(Half swipe),while swipe opposite direction in second row, first row is closed.

Comment: @rafeek ah, sorry. I misunderstood it. yeah. that behavior is caused by the onTouchListener. in fact, any touch or move events outside the swiped item, will make the swiped item closed. in order to prevent that happen, you will need to use the MotionEvent argument to determine if it's a left swipe. if so, don't recover the swiped item.

Comment: LayoutHelper inside of onDraw is not found

Comment: @RRGT19 LayoutHelper is just a helper class covert dp to px. you can search it online

Comment: You might want to use `Paint.setAntiAlias(true)` and `Paint.setSubpixelText(true)`  inside `UnderlayButton`'s `onDraw()` to make the button text smoother (not pixelated)

Comment: Very late to the party here, but for the 'known bug, when you swipe an item diagonally from one item to another' issue that causes the text to jump slightly (which I found very distracting), I was able to fix it by replacing `notifyItemChanged(pos)` with `notifyDataSetChanged()` in `recoverSwipedItem()`

Comment: @param In `public boolean onSingleTapConfirmed(MotionEvent e)` below `if(button.onClick(e.getX(), e.getY())){` add the `recoverQueue.add(swipedPos);`, `swipedPos = -1;`, `recoverSwipedItem();` statements before the break

Answer (score 32):

Here is the Kotlin version based on the accepted answer approach. With some minor changes I managed to render the buttons width based on the intrinsic size of the text instead of using a fixed width.

Demo project: https://github.com/ntnhon/RecyclerViewRowOptionsDemo

[image]

Implementation of `SwipeHelper`:

```
import android.annotation.SuppressLint
import android.content.Context
import android.graphics.*
import android.view.MotionEvent
import android.view.View
import androidx.annotation.ColorRes
import androidx.core.content.ContextCompat
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.ItemTouchHelper
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
import java.util.*
import kotlin.math.abs
import kotlin.math.max

abstract class SwipeHelper(
    private val recyclerView: RecyclerView
) : ItemTouchHelper.SimpleCallback(
    ItemTouchHelper.ACTION_STATE_IDLE,
    ItemTouchHelper.LEFT
) {
    private var swipedPosition = -1
    private val buttonsBuffer: MutableMap<Int, List<UnderlayButton>> = mutableMapOf()
    private val recoverQueue = object : LinkedList<Int>() {
        override fun add(element: Int): Boolean {
            if (contains(element)) return false
            return super.add(element)
        }
    }

    @SuppressLint("ClickableViewAccessibility")
    private val touchListener = View.OnTouchListener { _, event ->
        if (swipedPosition < 0) return@OnTouchListener false
        buttonsBuffer[swipedPosition]?.forEach { it.handle(event) }
        recoverQueue.add(swipedPosition)
        swipedPosition = -1
        recoverSwipedItem()
        true
    }

    init {
        recyclerView.setOnTouchListener(touchListener)
    }

    private fun recoverSwipedItem() {
        while (!recoverQueue.isEmpty()) {
            val position = recoverQueue.poll() ?: return
            recyclerView.adapter?.notifyItemChanged(position)
        }
    }

    private fun drawButtons(
        canvas: Canvas,
        buttons: List<UnderlayButton>,
        itemView: View,
        dX: Float
    ) {
        var right = itemView.right
        buttons.forEach { button ->
            val width = button.intrinsicWidth / buttons.intrinsicWidth() * abs(dX)
            val left = right - width
            button.draw(
                canvas,
                RectF(left, itemView.top.toFloat(), right.toFloat(), itemView.bottom.toFloat())
            )

            right = left.toInt()
        }
    }

    override fun onChildDraw(
        c: Canvas,
        recyclerView: RecyclerView,
        viewHolder: RecyclerView.ViewHolder,
        dX: Float,
        dY: Float,
        actionState: Int,
        isCurrentlyActive: Boolean
    ) {
        val position = viewHolder.adapterPosition
        var maxDX = dX
        val itemView = viewHolder.itemView

        if (actionState == ItemTouchHelper.ACTION_STATE_SWIPE) {
            if (dX < 0) {
                if (!buttonsBuffer.containsKey(position)) {
                    buttonsBuffer[position] = instantiateUnderlayButton(position)
                }

                val buttons = buttonsBuffer[position] ?: return
                if (buttons.isEmpty()) return
                maxDX = max(-buttons.intrinsicWidth(), dX)
                drawButtons(c, buttons, itemView, maxDX)
            }
        }

        super.onChildDraw(
            c,
            recyclerView,
            viewHolder,
            maxDX,
            dY,
            actionState,
            isCurrentlyActive
        )
    }

    override fun onMove(
        recyclerView: RecyclerView,
        viewHolder: RecyclerView.ViewHolder,
        target: RecyclerView.ViewHolder
    ): Boolean {
        return false
    }

    override fun onSwiped(viewHolder: RecyclerView.ViewHolder, direction: Int) {
        val position = viewHolder.adapterPosition
        if (swipedPosition != position) recoverQueue.add(swipedPosition)
        swipedPosition = position
        recoverSwipedItem()
    }

    abstract fun instantiateUnderlayButton(position: Int): List<UnderlayButton>

    //region UnderlayButton
    interface UnderlayButtonClickListener {
        fun onClick()
    }

    class UnderlayButton(
        private val context: Context,
        private val title: String,
        textSize: Float,
        @ColorRes private val colorRes: Int,
        private val clickListener: UnderlayButtonClickListener
    ) {
        private var clickableRegion: RectF? = null
        private val textSizeInPixel: Float = textSize * context.resources.displayMetrics.density // dp to px
        private val horizontalPadding = 50.0f
        val intrinsicWidth: Float

        init {
            val paint = Paint()
            paint.textSize = textSizeInPixel
            paint.typeface = Typeface.DEFAULT_BOLD
            paint.textAlign = Paint.Align.LEFT
            val titleBounds = Rect()
            paint.getTextBounds(title, 0, title.length, titleBounds)
            intrinsicWidth = titleBounds.width() + 2 * horizontalPadding
        }

        fun draw(canvas: Canvas, rect: RectF) {
            val paint = Paint()

            // Draw background
            paint.color = ContextCompat.getColor(context, colorRes)
            canvas.drawRect(rect, paint)

            // Draw title
            paint.color = ContextCompat.getColor(context, android.R.color.white)
            paint.textSize = textSizeInPixel
            paint.typeface = Typeface.DEFAULT_BOLD
            paint.textAlign = Paint.Align.LEFT

            val titleBounds = Rect()
            paint.getTextBounds(title, 0, title.length, titleBounds)

            val y = rect.height() / 2 + titleBounds.height() / 2 - titleBounds.bottom
            canvas.drawText(title, rect.left + horizontalPadding, rect.top + y, paint)

            clickableRegion = rect
        }

        fun handle(event: MotionEvent) {
            clickableRegion?.let {
                if (it.contains(event.x, event.y)) {
                    clickListener.onClick()
                }
            }
        }
    }
    //endregion
}

private fun List<SwipeHelper.UnderlayButton>.intrinsicWidth(): Float {
    if (isEmpty()) return 0.0f
    return map { it.intrinsicWidth }.reduce { acc, fl -> acc + fl }
}
```

Usage:

```
private fun setUpRecyclerView() {
        binding.recyclerView.adapter = Adapter(listOf(
            "Item 0: No action",
            "Item 1: Delete",
            "Item 2: Delete & Mark as unread",
            "Item 3: Delete, Mark as unread & Archive"
        ))
        binding.recyclerView.addItemDecoration(DividerItemDecoration(this, DividerItemDecoration.VERTICAL))
        binding.recyclerView.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(this)

        val itemTouchHelper = ItemTouchHelper(object : SwipeHelper(binding.recyclerView) {
            override fun instantiateUnderlayButton(position: Int): List<UnderlayButton> {
                var buttons = listOf<UnderlayButton>()
                val deleteButton = deleteButton(position)
                val markAsUnreadButton = markAsUnreadButton(position)
                val archiveButton = archiveButton(position)
                when (position) {
                    1 -> buttons = listOf(deleteButton)
                    2 -> buttons = listOf(deleteButton, markAsUnreadButton)
                    3 -> buttons = listOf(deleteButton, markAsUnreadButton, archiveButton)
                    else -> Unit
                }
                return buttons
            }
        })

        itemTouchHelper.attachToRecyclerView(binding.recyclerView)
    }

    private fun toast(text: String) {
        toast?.cancel()
        toast = Toast.makeText(this, text, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
        toast?.show()
    }

    private fun deleteButton(position: Int) : SwipeHelper.UnderlayButton {
        return SwipeHelper.UnderlayButton(
            this,
            "Delete",
            14.0f,
            android.R.color.holo_red_light,
            object : SwipeHelper.UnderlayButtonClickListener {
                override fun onClick() {
                    toast("Deleted item $position")
                }
            })
    }

    private fun markAsUnreadButton(position: Int) : SwipeHelper.UnderlayButton {
        return SwipeHelper.UnderlayButton(
            this,
            "Mark as unread",
            14.0f,
            android.R.color.holo_green_light,
            object : SwipeHelper.UnderlayButtonClickListener {
                override fun onClick() {
                    toast("Marked as unread item $position")
                }
            })
    }

    private fun archiveButton(position: Int) : SwipeHelper.UnderlayButton {
        return SwipeHelper.UnderlayButton(
            this,
            "Archive",
            14.0f,
            android.R.color.holo_blue_light,
            object : SwipeHelper.UnderlayButtonClickListener {
                override fun onClick() {
                    toast("Archived item $position")
                }
            })
    }
```

Comment: I downloaded the sample project and updated all the libraries to the latest version. Somehow the dragging isn't working properly.

Comment: not working after notifydataset changed or setting up adapter again

Answer (score 6):

I did the following to be able to draw a drawable instead of text:

1. In `SwipeHelper`, I changed

   ```
   UnderlayButton(String text, int imageResId, int color, UnderlayButtonClickListener clickListener)
   ```

   to

   ```
   UnderlayButton(String text, Bitmap bitmap, int color, UnderlayButtonClickListener clickListener)
   ```

   Of course I removed `imageResId` and instead created a `Bitmap bitmap` and passed the constructor variable to it using `this.bitmap = bitmap;` as the rest of the variables.
2. In `SwipeHelper.onDaw()` you may then call `drawBitmap()` to apply your bitmap to the canvas. For example:

   ```
   c.drawBitmap(bitmap, rect.left, rect.top, p);
   ```

   Where `c` and `p` and your Canvas and Paint variables respectively.
3. In the activity where I call `UnderlayButton`, I convert my drawable (in my case it is a `VectorDrawable`) to a bitmap using [this method](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38244327/9451458):

   ```
   int idDrawable = R.drawable.ic_delete_white;
   Bitmap bitmap = getBitmapFromVectorDrawable(getContext(), idDrawable);
   ```

What remains to be done is the centring of the icon.

Full onDraw method with text and bitmap both centered:

```java
public void onDraw(Canvas c, RectF rect, int pos){
            Paint p = new Paint();

            // Draw background
            p.setColor(color);
            c.drawRect(rect, p);

            // Draw Text
            p.setColor(Color.WHITE);
            p.setTextSize(24);


            float spaceHeight = 10; // change to whatever you deem looks better
            float textWidth = p.measureText(text);
            Rect bounds = new Rect();
            p.getTextBounds(text, 0, text.length(), bounds);
            float combinedHeight = bitmap.getHeight() + spaceHeight + bounds.height();
            c.drawBitmap(bitmap, rect.centerX() - (bitmap.getWidth() / 2), rect.centerY() - (combinedHeight / 2), null);
            //If you want text as well with bitmap
            c.drawText(text, rect.centerX() - (textWidth / 2), rect.centerY() + (combinedHeight / 2), p);

            clickRegion = rect;
            this.pos = pos;
        }
```

Comment: @TobySpeight  to centre the icon try this      c.drawBitmap(bitmap, rect.left+x/2 - 1, rect.top+y/2 - 4, p);

Answer (score 6):

For all those who wanna use a library for this, check this out:

https://github.com/chthai64/SwipeRevealLayout

And, for a stripped down version of this lib, checkout:

https://android.jlelse.eu/android-recyclerview-swipeable-items-46a3c763498d

P.S. You can create any custom layout (even with `Image Buttons`) as your hidden layout using these.

Answer (score 2):

Following Wenxi Zeng's answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45062745/3692155), if you want to have the text in the buttons on multiple lines, replace UnderlayButton's onDraw method with this:

```
public void onDraw(Canvas canvas, RectF rect, int pos){
        Paint p = new Paint();

        // Draw background
        p.setColor(color);
        canvas.drawRect(rect, p);

        // Draw Text
        TextPaint textPaint = new TextPaint();
        textPaint.setTextSize(UtilitiesOperations.convertDpToPx(getContext(), 15));
        textPaint.setColor(Color.WHITE);
        StaticLayout sl = new StaticLayout(text, textPaint, (int)rect.width(),
                Layout.Alignment.ALIGN_CENTER, 1, 1, false);

        canvas.save();
        Rect r = new Rect();
        float y = (rect.height() / 2f) + (r.height() / 2f) - r.bottom - (sl.getHeight() /2);
        canvas.translate(rect.left, rect.top + y);
        sl.draw(canvas);
        canvas.restore();

        clickRegion = rect;
        this.pos = pos;
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want button(s) on left side as well when swipe in the other direction, just try to add this simple lines in the [existing answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45062745/3049655):

1. In the `drawButtons` method:

   ```
   private void drawButtons(Canvas c, View itemView, List<UnderlayButton> buffer, int pos, float dX) {
       float right = itemView.getRight();
       float left = itemView.getLeft();
       float dButtonWidth = (-1) * dX / buffer.size();

       for (UnderlayButton button : buffer) {
           if (dX < 0) {
               left = right - dButtonWidth;
               button.onDraw(
                       c,
                       new RectF(
                               left,
                               itemView.getTop(),
                               right,
                               itemView.getBottom()
                       ),
                       pos, dX //(to draw button on right)
               );

               right = left;
           } else if (dX > 0) {
               right = left - dButtonWidth;
               button.onDraw(c,
                       new RectF(
                               right,
                               itemView.getTop(),
                               left,
                               itemView.getBottom()
                       ), pos, dX //(to draw button on left)
               );


           }
       }
   }
   ```
2. In the `onDraw` method check the value of `dX` and set the text and the colour of the buttons:

   ```
   public void onDraw(Canvas c, RectF rect, int pos, float dX) {
           Paint p = new Paint();

           // Draw background

           if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {


               if (dX > 0)
                   p.setColor(Color.parseColor("#23d2c5"));
               else if (dX < 0)
                   p.setColor(Color.parseColor("#23d2c5"));

               c.drawRect(rect, p);


               // Draw Text
               p.setColor(Color.WHITE);
               p.setTextSize(36);
               //  p.setTextSize(LayoutHelper.getPx(MyApplication.getAppContext(), 12));

               Rect r = new Rect();
               float cHeight = rect.height();
               float cWidth = rect.width();
               p.setTextAlign(Paint.Align.LEFT);
               p.getTextBounds(text, 0, text.length(), r);

               float x = cWidth / 2f - r.width() / 2f - r.left;
               float y = cHeight / 2f + r.height() / 2f - r.bottom;
               if (dX > 0) {
                   p.setColor(Color.parseColor("#23d2c5"));
                   c.drawText("Reject", rect.left + x, rect.top + y, p);
               } else if (dX < 0) {

                   c.drawText(text, rect.left + x, rect.top + y, p);
               }
               clickRegion = rect;
               this.pos = pos;
           }

       }
   ```

Answer (score 2):

I am late to the party but if anyone looks for an UIKit UITableView delete button behaviour then you can use something like this with a RecyclerView in Xamarin.Android:

```
public class SwipeDeleteHelper : ItemTouchHelper.Callback
{
    private int _startingWidth = 0;
    private bool? _rightAlignedText = null;
    private bool _alreadyClicked = false;

    private static float _previousDx = float.NegativeInfinity;
    private static float _viewWidth = float.NegativeInfinity;
    private static float _permanentlyDeleteThreshold = float.NegativeInfinity;

    private static RecyclerView.ViewHolder _currentViewHolder;
    private RecyclerView.ViewHolder CurrentViewHolder
    {
        get => _currentViewHolder;

        set
        {
            _startingWidth = 0;
            _rightAlignedText = null;
            _alreadyClicked = false;

            _previousDx = float.NegativeInfinity;

            _currentViewHolder = value;
        }
    }
    /*
    You can create a method in a utility class for the buttonwidth conversion like this:
    public static float GetPxFromDp(float dp)
    {
        return dp * Application.Context.ApplicationContext.Resources.DisplayMetrics.Density;
    }
    Also you can use text width measurement to determine the optimal width of the button for your delete text.
    */
    public static int buttonWidth = 60 * Application.Context.ApplicationContext.Resources.DisplayMetrics.Density;

    public override int GetMovementFlags(RecyclerView recyclerView, RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder)
    {
        if (viewHolder is EntryCell)
        {
            return MakeMovementFlags(ItemTouchHelper.ActionStateIdle, ItemTouchHelper.Left | ItemTouchHelper.Start | ItemTouchHelper.Right | ItemTouchHelper.End);
        }

        return MakeMovementFlags(ItemTouchHelper.ActionStateIdle, ItemTouchHelper.ActionStateIdle);
    }

    public override void OnSelectedChanged(RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder, int actionState)
    {
        if (float.IsNegativeInfinity(_permanentlyDeleteThreshold))
        {
            _viewWidth = viewHolder.ItemView.Width;
            _permanentlyDeleteThreshold = (viewHolder.ItemView.Width * 3f / 4f);
        }

        if (viewHolder != CurrentViewHolder)
        {
            if (viewHolder != null) // This is a new selection and the button of the previous viewHolder should get hidden.
            {
                (CurrentViewHolder as EntryCell)?.ResetView(CurrentViewHolder);

                CurrentViewHolder = viewHolder;
            }
            else if (CurrentViewHolder != null) // This is the end of the previous selection
            {
                var hidden = CurrentViewHolder.ItemView.FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.fileListDeleteButton);

                _previousDx = float.NegativeInfinity;

                if (hidden.LayoutParameters.Width > _permanentlyDeleteThreshold && !_alreadyClicked) // released in permanent delete area
                {
                    _alreadyClicked = true;

                    hidden.LayoutParameters.Width = CurrentViewHolder.ItemView.Width;

                    hidden.CallOnClick();

                    CurrentViewHolder = null;
                }
                else
                {
                    _startingWidth = hidden.LayoutParameters.Width >= buttonWidth ? buttonWidth : 0;

                    hidden.LayoutParameters.Width = _startingWidth;
                }

                AlignDeleteButtonText(hidden);

                hidden.RequestLayout();
            }
        }

        base.OnSelectedChanged(viewHolder, actionState);
    }

    public override void OnChildDraw(Canvas c, RecyclerView recyclerView, RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder, float dX, float dY, int actionState, bool isCurrentlyActive)
    {
        if (actionState == ItemTouchHelper.ActionStateSwipe && !_alreadyClicked)
        {
            var hidden = viewHolder.ItemView.FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.fileListDeleteButton);

            if (isCurrentlyActive) // swiping
            {
                if (float.IsNegativeInfinity(_previousDx)) // This is a new swipe
                {
                    _previousDx = dX;
                }

                if (Math.Abs(dX - _previousDx) > 0.1f && Math.Abs(dX - (-_viewWidth)) > 0.1f)
                {
                    hidden.LayoutParameters.Width = Math.Max(0, (int)Math.Round(hidden.LayoutParameters.Width - (dX >= _previousDx ? 1 : -1) * (Math.Abs(dX - _previousDx))));

                    _previousDx = dX;

                    AlignDeleteButtonText(hidden);

                    hidden.RequestLayout();
                }
            }
        }
    }

    private void AlignDeleteButtonText(Button hidden)
    {
        if (_rightAlignedText != false && hidden.LayoutParameters.Width >= _permanentlyDeleteThreshold) // pulled into permanent delete area
        {
            hidden.Gravity = GravityFlags.AxisSpecified | GravityFlags.AxisPullBefore | GravityFlags.CenterVertical;
            _rightAlignedText = false;
        }
        else if (_rightAlignedText != null && hidden.LayoutParameters.Width <= buttonWidth)
        {
            hidden.Gravity = GravityFlags.Center;
            _rightAlignedText = null;
        }
        else if (_rightAlignedText != true && hidden.LayoutParameters.Width > buttonWidth && hidden.LayoutParameters.Width < _permanentlyDeleteThreshold) // pulled back from permanent delete area
        {
            hidden.Gravity = GravityFlags.AxisSpecified | GravityFlags.AxisPullAfter | GravityFlags.CenterVertical;
            _rightAlignedText = true;
        }
    }

    public override bool OnMove(RecyclerView recyclerView, RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder, RecyclerView.ViewHolder target) { return false; }

    public override void OnSwiped(RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder, int direction) { }
}
```

The EntryCell is a descendant of MvxRecyclerViewHolder and it should contain something like this:

```
public class EntryCell : MvxRecyclerViewHolder
{
    public EntryCell(View itemView, IMvxAndroidBindingContext context) : base(itemView, context)
    {
        Button _delButton = itemView.FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.fileListDeleteButton);

        _delButton.Text = "Delete";
    }

    public void ResetView(RecyclerView.ViewHolder currentViewHolder)
    {
        var hidden = currentViewHolder.ItemView.FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.fileListDeleteButton);

        hidden.LayoutParameters.Width = 0;

        hidden.RequestLayout();
    }
}
```

Your view should have a button (Referenced in EntryCell as Resource.Id.fileListDeleteButton so the ID of the button is fileListDeleteButton) in it. I use an XML as a view and it looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="40dp"
    android:orientation="vertical">

<!-- The rest of your code... -->

<Button
    android:id="@+id/fileListDeleteButton"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:paddingHorizontal="@dimen/abc_button_padding_horizontal_material"
    android:background="#f00"
    android:textColor="@android:color/white"
    android:textAllCaps="false"
    android:singleLine="true"
    android:ellipsize="none"
    android:text="dummy" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

In your code, where the RecyclerView is, use it like this:

```
ItemTouchHelper itemTouchHelper = new ItemTouchHelper(new SwipeDeleteHelper());
itemTouchHelper.AttachToRecyclerView(yourRecyclerView);
```

I hope this helps someone.

Answer (score 2):

[image]

SwipeHelper in Kotlin, it show only icon not text but if you want I can give code for text. I changed it from Wenxi Zeng answer to Kotlin and added some additions, Thanh-Nhon Nguyen's answer doesn't work properly when you return swipped item.

SwipeHelper Class

```
import android.annotation.SuppressLint
import android.content.Context
import android.graphics.*
import android.graphics.drawable.Drawable
import android.view.GestureDetector
import android.view.GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener
import android.view.MotionEvent
import android.view.View
import android.view.View.OnTouchListener
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.ItemTouchHelper
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
import java.util.*

@SuppressLint("ClickableViewAccessibility")
abstract class SwipeHelp( context: Context?, recyclerView: RecyclerView, animate: Boolean) :
    ItemTouchHelper.SimpleCallback(0, ItemTouchHelper.LEFT) {
    private val recyclerView: RecyclerView
    private lateinit var buttons: MutableList<UnderlayButton>
    private var swipedPos = -1
    private var swipeThreshold = 0.5f
    private val buttonsBuffer: MutableMap<Int, MutableList<UnderlayButton>>
    private var animate: Boolean? = null

    private val recoverQueue = object : LinkedList<Int>() {
        override fun add(element: Int): Boolean {
            return if (contains(element)) false else super.add(element)
        }
    }

    private val gestureListener: SimpleOnGestureListener = object : SimpleOnGestureListener() {
        override fun onSingleTapConfirmed(e: MotionEvent): Boolean {
            for (button in buttons) {
                if (button.onClick(e.x, e.y)) break
            }
            return true
        }
    }

    private val gestureDetector = GestureDetector(context, gestureListener)

    @SuppressLint("ClickableViewAccessibility")
    private val onTouchListener = OnTouchListener { _, e ->
        if (swipedPos < 0) {
            return@OnTouchListener false
        }

        val point = Point(e.rawX.toInt(), e.rawY.toInt())
        val swipedViewHolder = recyclerView.findViewHolderForAdapterPosition(swipedPos)
        val swipedItem = swipedViewHolder!!.itemView
        val rect = Rect()
        swipedItem.getGlobalVisibleRect(rect)

        if (e.action == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN || e.action == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP || e.action == MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE) {
            if (rect.top < point.y && rect.bottom > point.y) {
                gestureDetector.onTouchEvent(e)
            } else {
                recoverQueue.add(swipedPos)
                swipedPos = -1
                recoverSwipedItem()
            }
        }
        false
    }

    init {
        this.animate = animate
        this.recyclerView = recyclerView
        buttons = ArrayList()
        this.recyclerView.setOnTouchListener(onTouchListener)
        buttonsBuffer = HashMap()
        attachSwipe()
    }

    override fun onMove(
        recyclerView: RecyclerView,
        viewHolder: RecyclerView.ViewHolder,
        target: RecyclerView.ViewHolder
    ): Boolean {
        return false
    }

    override fun onSwiped(viewHolder: RecyclerView.ViewHolder, direction: Int) {
        val pos = viewHolder.adapterPosition
        if (swipedPos != pos) recoverQueue.add(swipedPos)
        swipedPos = pos
        if (buttonsBuffer.containsKey(swipedPos))
            buttons = buttonsBuffer[swipedPos]!!
        else
            buttons.clear()

        buttonsBuffer.clear()
        swipeThreshold = 0.5f * buttons.size * BUTTON_WIDTH
        recoverSwipedItem()
    }

    override fun getSwipeThreshold(viewHolder: RecyclerView.ViewHolder): Float {
        return swipeThreshold
    }

    override fun getSwipeEscapeVelocity(defaultValue: Float): Float {
        return 0.1f * defaultValue
    }

    override fun getSwipeVelocityThreshold(defaultValue: Float): Float {
        return 5.0f * defaultValue
    }

    override fun onChildDraw(
        c: Canvas,
        recyclerView: RecyclerView,
        viewHolder: RecyclerView.ViewHolder,
        dX: Float,
        dY: Float,
        actionState: Int,
        isCurrentlyActive: Boolean
    ) {
        val pos = viewHolder.adapterPosition
        var translationX = dX
        val itemView = viewHolder.itemView
        if (pos < 0) {
            swipedPos = pos
            return
        }
        if (actionState == ItemTouchHelper.ACTION_STATE_SWIPE) {
            if (dX < 0) {
                var buffer: MutableList<UnderlayButton> = ArrayList()
                if (!buttonsBuffer.containsKey(pos)) {
                    instantiateUnderlayButton(viewHolder, buffer)
                    buttonsBuffer[pos] = buffer
                } else {
                    buffer = buttonsBuffer[pos]!!
                }
                translationX = dX * buffer.size * BUTTON_WIDTH / itemView.width
                drawButtons(c, itemView, buffer, pos, translationX)
            }
        }
        super.onChildDraw(
            c,
            recyclerView,
            viewHolder,
            translationX,
            dY,
            actionState,
            isCurrentlyActive
        )
    }

    @Synchronized
    private fun recoverSwipedItem() {
        while (!recoverQueue.isEmpty()) {
            val pos = recoverQueue.poll()
            if (pos!! > -1) {
                recyclerView.adapter!!.notifyItemChanged(pos)
            }
        }
    }

    private fun drawButtons(
        c: Canvas,
        itemView: View,
        buffer: List<UnderlayButton>,
        pos: Int,
        dX: Float
    ) {
        var right = itemView.width.toFloat()
      //val left = itemView.width * 0.75.toFloat()

        for (button in buffer) {
        val left = right - (-1 * dX / buffer.size)
            button.onDraw(
                c,
                RectF(
                    left,
                    itemView.top.toFloat(),
                    right,
                    itemView.bottom.toFloat()
                ),
                pos
            )
            right = left
        }
    }

    private fun attachSwipe() {
        val itemTouchHelper = ItemTouchHelper(this)
        itemTouchHelper.attachToRecyclerView(recyclerView)
    }

    abstract fun instantiateUnderlayButton(
        viewHolder: RecyclerView.ViewHolder?,
        underlayButtons: MutableList<UnderlayButton>?
    )

    class UnderlayButton(
        private val imageResId: Drawable?,
        private val buttonBackgroundColor: Int,
        private val clickListener: UnderlayButtonClickListener
    ) {
        private var pos = 0
        private var clickRegion: RectF? = null

        fun onClick(x: Float, y: Float): Boolean {
            if (clickRegion != null && clickRegion!!.contains(x, y)) {
                clickListener.onClick(pos)
                return true
            }
            return false
        }

        fun onDraw(canvas: Canvas, rect: RectF, pos: Int) {
            val p = Paint()
            p.color = buttonBackgroundColor
            canvas.drawRect(rect, p)
            if (!animate) {
                val cHeight = rect.height()

                if (imageResId != null) {
                    imageResId.setBounds(
                        (rect.left + 50).toInt(),
                        (rect.top + cHeight / 2f).toInt(),
                        (rect.right - 50).toInt(),
                        (rect.bottom - cHeight / 10f).toInt()
                    )
                    imageResId.draw(canvas)
                }
            } else {
                if (imageResId != null) {
                    imageResId.setBounds(
                        (rect.left + 50).toInt(),
                        (rect.top + 15).toInt(),
                        (rect.right - 50).toInt(),
                        (rect.bottom - 15).toInt()
                    )
                    imageResId.draw(canvas)
                }
                canvas.save()
                canvas.restore()
            }
            clickRegion = rect
            this.pos = pos
        }
    }

    interface UnderlayButtonClickListener {
        fun onClick(pos: Int)
    }

    companion object {
        const val BUTTON_WIDTH = 200
        private const val animate: Boolean = true
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
import android.annotation.SuppressLint
import android.graphics.Color
import android.os.Bundle
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import androidx.core.content.res.ResourcesCompat
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    private lateinit var adapter: SwipeAdapter
    private val swipeArrayList: ArrayList<String> = ArrayList()

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        val binding: ActivityMainBinding = ActivityMainBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
        val view = binding.root
        setContentView(view)

        swipeArrayList.add("11111")
        swipeArrayList.add("22222")
        swipeArrayList.add("33333")
        swipeArrayList.add("44444")
        swipeArrayList.add("55555")

        binding.recyclerView.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(this)
        adapter = SwipeAdapter(swipeArrayList)
        binding.recyclerView.adapter = adapter

        object : SwipeHelp(this@MainActivity , binding.recyclerView, false) {
            @SuppressLint("ResourceType")
            override fun instantiateUnderlayButton(
                viewHolder: RecyclerView.ViewHolder?,
                underlayButtons: MutableList<UnderlayButton>?
            ) {
                underlayButtons?.add(UnderlayButton(
                    ResourcesCompat.getDrawable (this@MainActivity.resources, R.drawable.trash_icon, null),
                    Color.BLUE,
                    object : UnderlayButtonClickListener {
                        override fun onClick(pos: Int) {
                            swipeArrayList.removeAt(viewHolder!!.adapterPosition)
                            adapter.notifyItemRemoved(viewHolder.adapterPosition)
                        }
                    }
                ))
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This is a good approach.  It would be better if you could give a comprehensive solution to the original post. For example, SwipeHelper class that can accommodate both titles and/or icons, rather than giving an alternative to the title.

Comment: I have better than it, https://github.com/KenanTagili/Swipe-menu-for-Recycler-view-Kotlin-AndroidX-example

Answer (score 1):

Since I haven't seen anywhere how to implement this and I did manage to get this to work, I will post a solution to this problem that is working however it is in c# Xamarin Android.

If you need it native android you will have to convert it android native which shouldn't be really hard. I might do this at a later date if very requested.

This is my ItemHelper base class:

```
 internal abstract class ItemTouchHelperBase : ItemTouchHelper.Callback
    {
        protected RecyclerViewAdapterBase adapter;
        public int currentPosition = -1;
        public Rect ItemRect = new Rect();

        private Paint backgroundPaint = new Paint();
        private Rect backgroundBounds = new Rect();
        private TextPaint textPaint = new TextPaint();
        private string deleteText;
        private readonly float textWidth;
        private readonly float textHeight;

        public ItemTouchHelperBase()
        {
            backgroundPaint.Color = new Color(ContextCompat.GetColor(Application.Context, Resource.Color.delete_red));
            textPaint.Color = Color.White;
            textPaint.AntiAlias = true;
            textPaint.TextSize = FontHelper.GetFontSize(Application.Context, Resource.Dimension.font_size_button);
            deleteText = "  " + StringResource.delete + "  ";

            Rect textBounds = new Rect();
            textPaint.GetTextBounds(deleteText, 0, deleteText.Length, textBounds);

            textHeight = textBounds.Height();
            textWidth = textPaint.MeasureText(deleteText);
        }

        public override bool OnMove(RecyclerView recyclerView, RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder, RecyclerView.ViewHolder target)
        {
            return false;
        }

        public override void ClearView(RecyclerView recyclerView, RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder)
        {
            if (adapter != null)
            {
                ItemRect = new Rect();
            }
            base.ClearView(recyclerView, viewHolder);
        }

        public override void OnSwiped(RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder, int direction)
        {
        }

        public override void OnChildDraw(Canvas c, RecyclerView recyclerView, RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder, float dX, float dY, int actionState, bool isCurrentlyActive)
        {
            // Note: Don't create variables inside OnDraw due to performance issues
            try
            {
                if (actionState == ItemTouchHelper.ActionStateSwipe)
                {
                    if (dX <= 0) // Left swipe
                    {
                        // Swipe up to text width accordingly to ratio
                        dX /= viewHolder.ItemView.Right / textWidth;

                        //Draw background
                        backgroundBounds = new Rect(
                            viewHolder.ItemView.Right + (int) dX,
                            viewHolder.ItemView.Top,
                            viewHolder.ItemView.Right,
                            viewHolder.ItemView.Bottom);
                        c.DrawRect(backgroundBounds, backgroundPaint);

                        if (adapter != null)
                        {
                            ItemRect = backgroundBounds;
                        }

                        //Draw text
                        c.DrawText(
                            deleteText,
                            (float) viewHolder.ItemView.Right - textWidth, viewHolder.ItemView.Top + (viewHolder.ItemView.Height / 2) + (textHeight / 2),
                            textPaint);
                    }

                    base.OnChildDraw(c, recyclerView, viewHolder, dX, dY, actionState, isCurrentlyActive);
                }
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
            }
        }

        internal void AttachToRecyclerview(RecyclerView recycleview)
        {
            new ItemTouchHelper(this).AttachToRecyclerView(recycleview);
        }

        public void ClickOutsideDeleteButton()
        {
            try
            {
                if (currentPosition != -1)
                {
                    PutRowBackToDefault();
                }
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
            }
        }

        protected void PutRowBackToDefault()
        {
            adapter.NotifyItemChanged(currentPosition);
            currentPosition = -1;
        }
    }
```

Then on your item helper class you have:

```
 internal class MyItemsTouchHelperCallback : ItemTouchHelperBase
    {
        public MyItemsTouchHelperCallback (MyAdapter adapter)
        {
            this.adapter = adapter;
        }

        public override int GetMovementFlags(RecyclerView recyclerView, RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder)
        {
            try
            {
                if (currentPosition != -1 && currentPosition != viewHolder.AdapterPosition)
                {
                    PutRowBackToDefault();
                }
                currentPosition = viewHolder.AdapterPosition;
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
            }

            int swipeFlags = viewHolder is MyViewHolder ? ItemTouchHelper.Start : ItemTouchHelper.ActionStateIdle;
            return MakeMovementFlags(ItemTouchHelper.ActionStateIdle, swipeFlags);
        }
    }
```

Then on your activity you have:

Put this OnCreate

```
        recycleViewLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
        recycler_view_main.SetLayoutManager(recycleViewLayoutManager);
        recyclerAdapter = new MyAdapter(this, this);
        recycler_view_main.SetAdapter(recyclerAdapter);
        myItemsTouchHelperCallback = new MyItemsTouchHelperCallback (recyclerAdapter);
        myItemsTouchHelperCallback .AttachToRecyclerview(recycler_view_main);
```

Then on activity you override this method:

```
 public override bool DispatchTouchEvent(MotionEvent e)
            {
                int[] recyclerviewLocationOnScreen = new int[2];
                recycler_view_main.GetLocationOnScreen(recyclerviewLocationOnScreen);

                TouchEventsHelper.TouchUpEvent(
                    e.Action,
                    e.GetX() - recyclerviewLocationOnScreen[0],
                    e.GetY() - recyclerviewLocationOnScreen[1],
                    myItemsTouchHelperCallback .ItemRect,
                    delegate
                    {
                        // Delete your row
                    },
                    delegate
                    { myItemsTouchHelperCallback .ClickOutsideDeleteButton(); });


                return base.DispatchTouchEvent(e);
            }
```

This is the helper method i created to be used by the dispatch event:

```
internal static void TouchUpEvent(MotionEventActions eventActions, float x, float y, Rect rectangle, Action ActionDeleteClick, Action NormalClick)
        {
            try
            {
                if (rectangle.Contains((int) x, (int) y))
                {
                    //inside delete button
                    if (eventActions == MotionEventActions.Down)
                    {
                        isClick = true;
                    }
                    else if (eventActions == MotionEventActions.Up || eventActions == MotionEventActions.Cancel)
                    {
                        if (isClick)
                        {
                            ActionDeleteClick.Invoke();
                        }
                    }
                }
                else if (eventActions == MotionEventActions.Up ||
                         eventActions == MotionEventActions.Cancel ||
                         eventActions == MotionEventActions.Down)
                {
                    //click anywhere outside delete button
                    isClick = false;
                    if (eventActions == MotionEventActions.Down)
                    {
                        NormalClick.Invoke();
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
            }
        }
```

It is a bit complex but it works well. I have tested this in many ways. Let me know if you have any trouble implementing this

Answer (score 0):

If you use a `RecyclerView`, try to use `OnScrollListener`. Do something like this.

```
 private class YourOnScrollListener extends RecyclerView.OnScrollListener {

    private boolean directionLeft;

    @Override
    public void onScrollStateChanged(RecyclerView recyclerView, int newState) {
        if (newState == RecyclerView.SCROLL_STATE_IDLE) {
            if (directionLeft) drawButtons();
            //Draw buttons here if you want them to be drawn after scroll is finished
            //here you can play with states, to draw buttons or erase it whenever you want
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onScrolled(RecyclerView recyclerView, int dx, int dy) {
        super.onScrolled(recyclerView, dx, dy);
        if (dx < 0) directionLeft = true;
        else directionLeft = false;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I wanted to use this touch gesture in my app too, after working too much with Itemtouchhelper I decided to write my own touch handler:

```
    private class TouchHelper : Java.Lang.Object, View.IOnTouchListener
    {
        ViewHolder vh;
        public TouchHelper(ViewHolder vh)
        { this.vh = vh;  }

        float DownX, DownY; bool isSliding;
        TimeSpan tsDown;
        public bool OnTouch(View v, MotionEvent e)
        {
            switch (e.Action)
            {
                case MotionEventActions.Down:
                    DownX = e.GetX(); DownY = e.GetY();
                    tsDown = TimeSpan.Now;
                    break;
                case MotionEventActions.Move:
                    float deltaX = e.GetX() - DownX, deltaY = e.GetX() - DownY;
                    if (Math.Abs(deltaX) >= Values.ScreenWidth / 20 || Math.Abs(deltaY) >= Values.ScreenWidth / 20)
                        isSliding = Math.Abs(deltaX) > Math.Abs(deltaY);

                    //TextsPlace is the layout that moves with touch
                    if(isSliding)
                        vh.TextsPlace.TranslationX = deltaX / 2;

                    break;
                case MotionEventActions.Cancel:
                case MotionEventActions.Up:
                    //handle if touch was for clicking
                    if (Math.Abs(deltaX) <= 50 && (TimeSpan.Now - tsDown).TotalMilliseconds <= 400)
                        vh.OnTextsPlaceClick(vh.TextsPlace, null);
                    break;
            }
            return true;
        }
    }
```

Note: Set this as ontouchlistener of your viewholder content when **creating** the viewholder. You can add your animations to return the item to its first place.

You can also write your custom layoutmanager to block vertical scroll while item is sliding.

Answer (score 0):

I have a much simpler solution:

1. Add a button to your row XML, width 0, floating on the right:

> ```
> > <Button
> >     android:id="@+id/hidden"
> >     android:layout_width="0dp"
> >     android:layout_height="match_parent"
> >     android:layout_alignParentRight = "true">
> ```

2. in onChildDraw(), just increase its width by the dX value.

   ```
    int position = viewHolder.getAdapterPosition();
    View v = recyclerView.getLayoutManager().findViewByPosition(position);
    Button hidden = v.findViewById(R.id.hidden);
    hidden.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams((int)-dX, -1));
   ```

Make sure not to call the default super.onChildDraw()

Answer (score 0):

```
 public void onDraw(Canvas c, RectF rect, int pos){
        Paint p = new Paint();

        // Draw background
        p.setColor(color);
        c.drawRect(rect, p);



        // Draw Text
        p.setColor(Color.WHITE);
        p.setTextSize(25.0f);





        Rect r = new Rect();
        float cHeight = rect.height();
        float cWidth = rect.width();
        p.setTextAlign(Paint.Align.LEFT);
        p.getTextBounds(text, 0, text.length(), r);
        float x = cWidth / 2f - r.width() / 2f - r.left;
        float y = cHeight / 2f + r.height() / 2f - r.bottom;
        c.drawText(text, rect.left + x, rect.top + y + (r.height()*2), p);

        //Draw Image
        if (imageResId != 0){
            float textWidth = p.measureText(text);
            Bitmap bmp = drawableToBitmap(ContextCompat.getDrawable(context, imageResId));
            c.drawBitmap(bmp, rect.centerX()-(bmp.getWidth()/2f),rect.centerY()-(bmp.getHeight()/2f), null);
        }          

        clickRegion = rect;
        this.pos = pos;
    }
```

drawableToBitmap(ContextCompat.getDrawable(context, imageResId))

is function under the onDraw() you can create any icon into bitmap that show in your canvas

for drawableToBitmap() function is below

public static Bitmap drawableToBitmap (Drawable drawable) {
Bitmap bitmap = null;

```
        if (drawable instanceof BitmapDrawable) {
            BitmapDrawable bitmapDrawable = (BitmapDrawable) drawable;
            if(bitmapDrawable.getBitmap() != null) {
                return bitmapDrawable.getBitmap();
            }
        }

        if(drawable.getIntrinsicWidth() <= 0 || drawable.getIntrinsicHeight() <= 0) {
            bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(1, 1, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888); // Single color bitmap will be created of 1x1 pixel
        } else {
            bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(drawable.getIntrinsicWidth(), drawable.getIntrinsicHeight(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
        }

        Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bitmap);
        drawable.setBounds(0, 0, canvas.getWidth(), canvas.getHeight());
        drawable.draw(canvas);
        return bitmap;
    }
```

i hope this will help you

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4Gtep.jpg)

this is image link of view

> Blockquote

Comment: hey where you find this snippet
any ref.