# How to add an Delete image when item in recycler view is swiped to right

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, swipe-gesture, itemtouchhelper

I was implementing swipe to show `Delete` button in Recycler View , which I was able to do with the help of this `https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44965278/recyclerview-itemtouchhelper-buttons-on-swipe` .
But my requirement is to add an image along with the Delete option when swiped to right.

How can we the set the Image from the drawable to the `onDraw` Method. can someone help me on this. I have added an Image which I need to implement like the same.[image]

code::

```
 public static class UnderlayButton {
        private String text;
        private int imageResId;
        private int color;
        private int pos;
        private RectF clickRegion;
        private UnderlayButtonClickListener clickListener;

        public UnderlayButton(String text, int imageResId, int color, UnderlayButtonClickListener clickListener) {
            this.text = text;
            this.imageResId = imageResId;
            this.color = color;
            this.clickListener = clickListener;
        }

        public boolean onClick(float x, float y) {
            if (clickRegion != null && clickRegion.contains(x, y)) {
                clickListener.onClick(pos);
                return true;
            }

            return false;
        }

        public void onDraw(Canvas c, RectF rect, int pos) {
            Paint p = new Paint();

            // Draw background
            p.setColor(color);
            c.drawRect(rect, p);

            // Draw Text
            p.setColor(Color.WHITE);
            p.setTextSize(20);


            Rect r = new Rect();
            float cHeight = rect.height();
            float cWidth = rect.width();
            p.setTextAlign(Paint.Align.LEFT);
            p.getTextBounds(text, 0, text.length(), r);
            float x = cWidth / 2f - r.width() / 2f - r.left;
            float y = cHeight / 2f + r.height() / 2f - r.bottom;
            c.drawText(text, rect.left + x, rect.top + y, p);

            clickRegion = rect;
            this.pos = pos;
        }
    }
```

Comment: in onTouch() method, swipedViewHolder.itemView was null after deleting last item from adapter and list, any solution?  How can we fix that issue in the above code?